# Changing app permissions

Tags: settings

I am using Bluestacks to play a game.But every time i try to play game "Mini Motor Racing" it shows;

[image]

I also went to settings >Apps >Mini Motor Racing > but there is no selection of permissions so i can't change permission.I also search for it on google but nothing helped. Plz guide me if u can thanks bye.

Comment: These permissions handling are available in Android version 6 and above. I think it's most likely a bluestacks fault (It doesn't seem you are running this Android Version)

Comment: Please edit your question and info on the Android device do you use: manufacturer, product name, Android version?